# What is the difference between these two ways to get info in OOP in dart flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, oop, getter

What is the difference between these two ways to get info in OOP in dart flutter?

```
int get age {
    return vehicleAge;
}
```

```
int age() {
    return vehicleAge;
}
```

I undestand that the fisrt one is called with `.age` and the second with `age()`, but is that the only difference?

Comment: `get age` is a getter, you can think of as a filed , bt `age()` is a method